# How can I run typeORM migration automatically?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, docker, nestjs, typeorm

Has anyone encountered such a problem with typeORM version 0.3.17 trying to run migration automatically when app launched?

I'm using `typeorm` for a microservice project (run it with Docker) and apart from running `marging` automatically  everything works fine.

I have two files `dataSource` and `typeOrmConfig`:

**dataSource**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: './.env',
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'postgres',
        host: configService.get('POSTGRES_HOST'),
        port: configService.get('POSTGRES_PORT'),
        username: configService.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
        password: configService.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        database: configService.get('POSTGRES_DB'),
        ssl: configService.get('NODE_ENV') === 'production' ? true : false,
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        migrations: [`${__dirname}/migrations/*.{ts,js}`],
        entities: [`${__dirname}/libs/shared/src/entities/*.entity.{ts,js}`],
        migrationsTableName: 'migration_table',
        migrationsRun: true,
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
})
export class PostgresDBModule {}
```

**typeOrmConfig**

```
const configService = new ConfigService();

export default new DataSource({
  type: 'postgres',
  host: configService.get('POSTGRES_HOST'),
  port: configService.getOrThrow('POSTGRES_PORT'),
  database: configService.getOrThrow('POSTGRES_DB'),
  username: configService.getOrThrow('POSTGRES_USER'),
  password: configService.getOrThrow('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
  ssl: configService.get('NODE_ENV') === 'production' ? true : false,
  migrations: [`${__dirname}/migrations/*.{ts,js}`],
  entities: [`${__dirname}/libs/shared/src/entities/*.entity.{ts,js}`],
  migrationsRun: true,
  migrationsTableName: 'migration_table',
});
```

It seems that the property `migrationsRun:true` is not working or I am missing something in the configuration.

Comment: In `PostgresDBModule`, can you check that `[`${__dirname}/migrations/*.{ts,js}`]` is a valid relative path to `PostgresDBModule` file?

Comment: hi @fujy Thanks for the response, I will check it now and let you know.